# Error 400 Spring Json @RequestBody when doing post

Tags: java, json, spring, web

Here are the classes involve.

```
public class UserAuthDto {

    private String username;

    private String password;

    private List<String> roles;

    private String tenantCode;

    public UserAuthDto(String username,
                           String password,
                           List<String> roles,
                           String tenantCode){
        this.username=username;
        this.password=password;
        this.roles=roles;
        this.tenantCode=tenantCode;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setRoles(List<String> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    public void setTenantCode(String tenantCode) {
        this.tenantCode = tenantCode;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public List<String> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public String getTenantCode() {
        return tenantCode;
    }
}
```

Another DTO

```
public class UserAuthRequest {

    private UserAuthDto userAuthDto;

    public UserAuthRequest(UserAuthDto authDto){
        if(authDto == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("User Authentication DTO Should Not be null");
        }
        this.userAuthDto = authDto;
    }
    public String getUsername(){
        return userAuthDto.getUsername();
    }

    public String getPassword(){
        return userAuthDto.getPassword();
    }

    public List<String> getRoles(){
        return  userAuthDto.getRoles();
    }

    public String getTenantCode(){
        return  userAuthDto.getTenantCode();
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.userAuthDto.setUsername(username);
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.userAuthDto.setPassword(password);
    }

    public void setRoles(List<String> roles) {
        this.userAuthDto.setRoles(roles);
    }

    public void setTenantCode(String tenantCode) {
        this.userAuthDto.setTenantCode(tenantCode);
    }
}
```

And here's the Controller that was processing the request.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "authenticate", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes = "application/json",produces = "application/json")
    public UserAuthResponse authenticate(@RequestBody UserAuthRequest authRequest){
       //.
    }
```

However when I send this data

```
{"username": "test","password":"test","roles":null,"tenantCode":"test"}
```

I receive a 400 bad request. any idea why?

Comment: Your `UserAuthRequest` pojo doesn't match the JSON you give it, structurally.

Comment: But also, turn your Spring logs to DEBUG level. It will tell you what's wrong, at least why the deserialization failed.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis What should be the JSON format then? and how do I set spring Logs to debug level?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring uses Jackson to map the JSON in the request to Java objects to pass as arguments to your handler method.

Here are [the JSON types](http://json.org/). Here's how Jackson does JSON mappings:

1. JSON objects map to Java `Map` or custom class objects

   - The keys of JSON object key-value pairs map to class instance fields
2. JSON arrays map to Java arrays or `Collection` types (`List`, `Set`, etc.)
3. JSON numbers map to Java numerical types (`int`, `double`, `Long`, etc. Both primitive and reference types)
4. JSON strings map to Java `String` objects (or fields if the JSON string is a key)
5. JSON null maps to Java `null`
6. JSON false and true map to Java `false` and `true`.

You've provided the following JSON

```
{"username": "test","password":"test","roles":null,"tenantCode":"test"}
```

This is a JSON object, with 4 key-value pairs, where the keys are `username`, `password`, `roles`, and `tenantCode`. So you need a Java class with fields (or properties) with those names. You have such a class, `UserAuthDto`. That's what you should use as your parameter type.

---

You can enable logging by providing the appropriate slf4j and logback or log4j libraries on the classpath with an appropriate configuration for Spring's loggers.

Comment: Thanks quick question though, can you provide an example for Spring loggers? I already have log4j in my classpath

Comment: @user962206 That's not a quick question. There are few pieces involved. A tutorial might be better suited. See [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/logging_with_log4j.htm) for a log4j example. Or see [this](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-log-in-spring-with-slf4j-and-logback/) for a logback example (I prefer logback).

Answer (score 3):

I struggled this morning with a similar problem. I got a 400 even when the object I was sending was correct. My class was something like this:

```
class myClass {
   AnalysisResult average; //AnalysisResult is a List<double>
   AnalysisResult worstCase;
   public MyClass(AnalysisResult average, AnalysisResult worstCase) {
      //initializations
   }
}
```

It was solved by adding a default constructor:

```
class myClass {
   AnalysisResult average; //AnotherClass is a List<double>
   AnalysisResult worstCase;
   public MyClass(AnalysisResult average, AnalysisResult worstCase) {
      //initializations
   }
   public MyClass() {}
}
```

It seems that, for some classes, jackson requires a default constructor